# Delete an object within an outer object not working

Tags: javascript

Currently trying to delete an object within another object using the delete keyword as I've seen all around the web. The object I'm using is similar to the one below:

```
object = { NAME: {hello: 3838383, goodbye: 3474737}, NAME2: {hello: 3838383, goodbye: 3474737} }
```

Trying:

```
delete object.NAME
```

But I continually get: Cannot delete property 'NAME' of [object Object]. Any ideas?

Comment: I've just tried this in my console and worked, any other details that you can provide?

Comment: Well this response object is coming from an observable I subscribe to so perhaps it isn't a JSON object. Is there some type of objectfy function I can apply to it?

Comment: @paulgio - It's definitely not JSON, because it's not a string. :-) JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `NAME` is a *non-configurable* property. That means you can't delete it I'm afraid, as deleting (removing) a property counts as "configuring" it (as does changing the `configurable` flag on the property).

You can see what the configuration of the property is by using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`. In your case it probably will either not show a `configurable` property at all (because `false` is the default) or more likely it'll show `configurable: false`.

Here's an example which shows using `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and demonstrates the error you're getting:

```js
"use strict";
const object = { };
Object.defineProperty(object, "NAME", {
    value: {hello: 3838383, goodbye: 3474737},
    configurable: false,
    writable: true
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, "NAME"));
delete object.NAME;
```

**If** the property is `writable`, you can assign some other value to itm, such as `null` or `undefined`:

```
object.NAME = null;
```

But if it's also non-writable, you can't do that, either.

As a final resort, you could create a *new* object and only copy the properties to it that you want, and assign that new object to the variable or property you're using to refer to the object. For instance:

```
object = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object)
      .filter(([key]) => key !== "NAME")
);
```

Live Example:

```js
"use strict";
let object = {
    NAME2: {hello: 3838383, goodbye: 3474737}
};
Object.defineProperty(object, "NAME", {
    value: {hello: 3838383, goodbye: 3474737},
    configurable: false, // Just here for emphasis, false is the default
    writable: false      // same
});
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(object, "NAME"));

// Can't do this: delete object.NAME;
object = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(object)
      .filter(([key]) => key !== "NAME")
);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way around using Object.fromEntries?

Comment: @paulgio - You can loop over `Object.entries` or similar, but if the property is non-configurable, you can't delete it; if it's non-writable, you can't change it.